# echo value and store as variable

Tags: php, curl, echo

```
$ch = curl_init();                   //this part we set up curl 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$xml_response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
header('Content-type: application/xml');  //specify as xml to not display as one long string
echo $xml_response; 
//header('Content-type: text/plain');  //specify as xml to not display as one long string
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_response);  //time to echo back the correct piece of data

$editorialReview = $xml->Items->Item->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview->Content;
ob_start();
echo '<p>Editorial review: '.html_entity_decode($editorialReview).'</p>'."\n"; 
$MineNow = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
var_dump($MineNow);
```

what i want to do is after the echo i need to store it into a variable so i can post
the data into mysql; i tried using ob_start session to capture it but var_dump is not returning any vaules!!

Comment: `var_dump` always echoes something, even if it's empty string ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you just use:

```
$variable = '<p>Editorial review: '.html_entity_decode($editorialReview).'</p>'."\n";
echo $variable;
```